# How do you use laravel braces with html attributes?

Tags: dynamic, laravel-blade, laravel-8, conditional-operator

I am having trouble writing simple logic using blade when attributes are involved for instance

```
<a href='#' class= {!!$activeCategory==$category->id ? 
                        'accordion-toggle active ' :  
                        'accordion-toggle inactive ' 
                    !!} />
```

i want it such that i can switch between the two last classes for my tag. also the first item remains unchanged i cannot concatenate as i cant use braces midway an attribute, however still when using it like this for some reason only the first word is set in the class string and the last is broken out of the string into just a hanging attribute. i hate that . how can i solve this and still write it in an concise manner or what's the trick in working with those curly braces in laravel, there always seems to be a catch  each and every other time unlike how it works in other templating engines. the following is the created code on element inspect

```
 <a href='#' class="accordion-toggle" active />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things:

- You don't need `{!! !!}` for non-html `{{ }}` is fine
- Don't repeat "accordion-toggle"; put it outside the braces
- Wrap *everything* in `" "`, use `' '` in the braces:

```html
<a href="#" class="accordion-toggle {{ $activeCategory == $category->id ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}"> ...
```

Comment: Thanks mehn, that was fast response.  thank you very much saved me headache. however i have isolated the problem to any variable containing spaces rather and it is not even a problem of conditional logic consider this. 
                {{$clzStrng= $activeCategory==$category->id? 'something active ':'accordion-toggle inactive '}}   then you want to add clzString as an attribute this time no way to reduce to a single class. how would you handle that

Comment: i already did but it wont register because am yet to get reputation, it will probably be registered once i go up ranks. ok on the comment i suppose it is better i create another question and you answer that one there ?

Comment: Nope, that's ok, 1 question here is fine. I forgot about that rule, so don't worry about it :)

Comment: unfortunately I cant post until another 90 minutes, could you answer my query in the comment above. i.e. how can i use a variable with whitespaces in it as the value to assign to an attribute. it seems to break it into individual attribute at every single whitespace boundary.

Comment: `class="{{ $activeCategory == $category->id? 'something active' : 'accordion-toggle inactive' }}"`; wrap _everything_ in `" "` to avoid having it split.

Comment: ahaaaa now i got it. damn that's neat, then again thank you . ok the only remaining issue is with complex logic, some linters in vs-code break and the default one fails to syntax-highlight correctly but i can deal with that thank you very much.

Comment: Excellent! Usage of `{{ }}` is pretty interesting, and you'll run into some weird situations. As for the Linter, you'll need to find something that supports `.blade.php` formatting. Funny enough, something like `class="{{ "something" }}"` is actually valid, even though at a glance, it looks like it would break (mis-matched " pairs). But anyway, play with it a bit more, and don't hesitate to reach out if you have any more issues. Cheers!